# Mage_Page_Block_Html_Toplinks @deprecated after 1.4.0.1, CE 1.8

Tags: ce-1.8.0.0, toplinks

I saw on `RELEASE_NOTES.txt` on CE 1.8:

> - Fixed #17451: Header Links (top.links.phtml) does not output
>     correctly because it is using the model code (the Toplinks block is
>     deprecated)

However, the `$this->getChildHtml('topLinks')` call on the demo frontend template seems to output links which `addLink` method of `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Toplinks` created: shopping cart, login etc.

I didn't understand that. What is the supposed way of adding those links ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Mage_Page_Block_Html_Toplinks` is indeed deprecated since 1.4.0.1. The new block for adding links is now `Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links`, which also holds a `addLink` method. If you check the page.xml you will notice the new block within the header block: `<block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>`.

So the functionality stays the same, although this new block is more a generic solution instead of just for the header top links.

Comment: this helps me very well :)